# Why does this JavaScript code return "Get some more shut eye"?

Tags: javascript

I don't see what went wrong in this block of code

```js
 var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
   if (sleepCheck >= 8) {
     return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
   } else {
     return "Get some more shut eye!";
   }
 }
 sleepCheck(10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sleepCheck` is a function.

If you treat it as a number, it will evaluate to `0` (or maybe `NaN`, but certainly not something larger than 0).

But this looks to be a simple typo, you wanted

```
if (numHours >= 8){
```

Comment: simple typo => you should follow the script's advice :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the right variable.

Replace

```
if (sleepCheck >= 8){
```

with

```
if (numHours>= 8){
```